# Not able to use classes from an external proyect with maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Hello I have to maven projects; I need to use the classes from a second project in my main one, right now I am able to see the project in the dependencies tab, I am using intellij:

[image]

And also in the external libraries section:

[image]

But I am not able to use the classes from my second project in my main project, I got the message:

[image]

I am adding the dependency in my first project such as:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.lift</groupId>
      <artifactId>container-system</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

This is how is configured my second project:

```
    <groupId>com.lift</groupId>
    <artifactId>container-system</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>console-container</name>
    <description>container executor </description>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Define the second project as a module of the main project in your main pom.xml or in another module of the main project, so that both projects form a single projects tree. Refresh/import again the projects in your IDE. Verify that both mave projects are shown in the IDE as IDE projects.

Comment: Install the JAR into your local Maven repository (typically .m2 in your home folder)

Comment: If you have this Maven project on your system - import in into the current IDE project - then IDE will use the project sources as a dependency rather than the jar form the Maven local repository.